# What is the best way to free up memory from a TypedArray in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I understand fully that the garbage collector will eventually do it's job and free up the memory allocated in a `TypedArray` in exactly the same way as it would any variable or object (assuming there are no circular references etc).

However, I am doing a lot of continuous processing in a number of `WebWorkers` and I would therefore like to have this memory freed as soon as possible by the GC.  Using normal `JavaScript` arrays, simply setting `array.length = 0;` is a good way a doing exactly this, but what about when using TypedArray's?

Would the following result in the memory being freed as soon as possible?

```
var testArray = new Uint8Array(buffer);

///Do stuff with testArray

tesArray.length = 0;
```

Or since the TypedArray is simply a view over the `ArrayBuffer`, would I need to clear the actual buffer itself also?  If so, how?

Comment: Why not use testArray = null? I have seen this approach being used a lot.

Comment: If nulling the array is indeed the best way to do so, and is actually effective, then great, i'll use that.  But my concern was that the actual underlying buffer itself gets left behind and cleaned up by the GC later.

Comment: Good point, I thought that GCs nowaways are smart enough to take care of this.

Comment: Indeed, you're quite right, that's very likely to be the case.  But I was hoping someone had some insight or experience that could offer a more complete explanation of what modern browsers actually do behind the scenes with regards to TypedArray's.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nulling the references to the typed array should be good enough. Setting `.length = 0` does not work, as - in contrast to usual arrays - the [`length` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/TypedArray/length) is readonly.

Should you really experience problems with the garbage collector, I would recommend to try *reusing* the same buffer over and over, instead of allocating new ones all the time and hoping for them to get freed.

Comment: [Nulling the reference to a typed array - that doesn't really work.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69746288/garbage-collector-doesnt-work-for-typed-arrays-in-nodejs-chrome)

Answer (score -1):

Following [@Bergi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1048572/bergi)'s advice, and [@vitaly-t](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1102051/vitaly-t)'s note, I came up with this:

```js
/**
 * Dereferences a list of objects and prepares them for garbage collection
 * @simply PrepareForGarbageCollection(...objects:any) → void
 *
 * @param {...any} objects  The list of objects to dereference
 */
function PrepareForGarbageCollection(...objects) {
    // @performance
    for(let object of objects) {
        if(object === void null || object === null)
            continue;

        if([Map, WeakMap, Set, WeakSet].find(constructor => object instanceof constructor))
            object.clear();
        else if([Array, Uint8Array, Uint8ClampedArray, Uint16Array, Uint32Array, Int8Array, Int16Array, Int32Array, Float32Array, Float64Array, BigInt64Array, BigUint64Array].find(constructor => object instanceof constructor))
            object.fill(0, 0, object.length - 1);
        else if(object instanceof Object)
            for(let key in object) {
                // @deep → PrepareForGarbageCollection(object[key]);
                delete object[key];
            }
        delete object;
    }
}
```

1. It dereferences as much *crap* as possible and empties huge arrays
2. It dereferences the object(s) as well

Comment: For my use-case (a chrome extension), it took my overhead from an unpredictable 3GB (±2GB) down to a consistent 300MB (±50MB)

Comment: `delete object;` does not do what you think it does.

Comment: `object.fill(0, 0, object.length - 1)` is totally pointless on typed arrays