# Garbage collector doesn't work for typed arrays in NodeJS / Chrome

Tags: javascript, node.js

I initially logged this as [an issue in the original project](https://github.com/nodejs/help/issues/3590), which was moved right away into help topics, without a good explanation, so now I'm trying to ask here.

---

If we run the following code in NodeJS (v14, v16, v17):

```js
let arr = new Array(1e8);

for(const a of arr) {
}

console.log('releasing...');
arr = null;

setTimeout(() => {
}, 1e6); // let the process hang idle
```

The process memory is released instantly by GC, and so it sits at ~ 10MB.

Now, if we just swap to any typed array, say `Uint8Array`:

```js
let arr = new Uint8Array(1e8);

for(const a of arr) {
}

console.log('releasing...');
arr = null;

setTimeout(() => {
}, 1e6); // let the process hang idle
```

Now the process memory sits at ~108MB permanently, it is never released.

In the original post, I had a reply about "not enough memory" being used. This didn't make any sense to me, because if I increase the array size to 1e9, the same occurs, except for the typed array the process now sits at 1GB, permanently. For a single NodeJS process, that is a lot.

Can anyone please explain, if what I'm looking at is a genuine bug or something I do not understand?

**UPDATE**

My tests indicate that it may have something to do with the specific of the `for-of` iterator for typed arrays, because if I remove `for-of` iterator, and instead use the following:

```js
let t;
for(let i = 0;i < arr.length;i ++) {
  t += arr[i]; 
}
```

then suddenly the memory is released correctly. I wonder now if typed arrays have a bug inside their iterator implementation, one that leaks or freezes memory.

---

Tested on Windows 10, with NodeJS v14, v16 and v17

Comment: Don't assume that Node is going to release every bit of freed memory back to the operating system. It may hold on to it for later use by the program it's running. Memory allocation has a cost and if your program has used 1GB already, it seems pretty likely that it will use that much at some later time, so better to hold on to it. If it's not ever actually used again, the OS will swap it out anyway.

Comment: @kindall This does not explain the huge discrepancy between regular and typed arrays.

Comment: I have no difficulty believing that Node manages the memory used by different types of objects differently or based on any of a dozen different critiria. The question is, if you free and then re-allocate 1 GB of memory, does it go up another 1 GB? Or does it re-use the GB it already has?

Comment: @kindall `if you free` - free how? We can't free it, that's the problem.

Comment: It's a garbage-collected language. If there's no reference to something, it goes away. So make there be no reference to your huge array. Then, make another huge array the same size. You're fixated on "releasing to the OS" as the definition of "freeing." If your program can reuse it, it's free, even if it hasn't been released to the OS.

Comment: I'm not saying it's impossible that you've uncovered a bug... or at least poor behavior... but just because it doesn't act as you expect, doesn't mean it's broken.

Comment: `If there's no reference to something, it goes away` - do you not see that the example I provided has no reference to the array? In fact, I even set it to `null`, just in case. Nothing helps. I'm not gonna take it on faith, I'm a developer, and I see a problem there.

Comment: Have you tried forcing a garbage collection cycle? I would expect V8 not try to free the memory until something else actually needs it.

Comment: You say in your `Array` test, "*the process memory is released instantly by GC*", but how did you confirm this? Notice that `new Array(1e8)` is a sparse array, it doesn't actually allocate a gigabyte of memory unlike the typed arrays's buffer does. Try what happens when you `arr.fill(42)`.

Answer (score 1):

The garbage collector is working. Node reuses or frees the memory at some point, just not at a defined point.

Here is a test application that allocates an array, holds on to a second, releases the variable, then repeats. The allocated memory of the application does what we expect: it fluctuates up and down. If the garbage collector wasn't working it would just go up.

```
function allocatedAndDeallocateArray(callback) {
    let arr = new Uint8Array(1e8);
    setTimeout(
        () => {
            for(const a of arr) {
            }
            arr = null;
            callback();
        },
        1000
    );
}

let count = 0;
function performAllocation() {
    if(++count < 180) {
        console.log(`${count}: Allocating new array!`);
        allocatedAndDeallocateArray(performAllocation);
    }
}

performAllocation();
```

Comment: This example doesn't do it - see the update I have in my question. It would need to make use of an iterator, to be a valid example.

Comment: @vitaly-t: I changed it so that it accessed the array via an index, and sure enough the memory usage fluctuated a lot less. (It never exceed 8 MB, while if it used the `of` keyword it would sometimes go above 100MB). 
This is an Interesting oddity, but I would not call it a defect.

Comment: A little bigger buffer size - it jumps over 1GB, and dies shortly after. Still not a defect? :)